# mysql real escape string removing get variable

Tags: mysql-real-escape-string

I have a page that takes a GET variable from the URL and checks it against a mysql database like so:

```
<?php 
$t=$_GET['t']; 
//check against database
?>
<div><?php echo $t; ?></div>
```

This works. However, when I add the `mysql_real_escape_string` on the get variable like:

```
$t=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['t']);
```

the variable disappears.  Nothing is inside the div and I don't know why.  I have tried many ordinary strings and they all disappear.

Answer (score 1):

you have to connect to a database before `using mysql_real_escape_string();`

Comment: Ahhhhh lol so simple, but exactly what was wrong for me.  Using mysql_real_escape right BEFORE my connect code, duh!